# Missing all the accent in DuckDB ODBC

Tags: powerbi, odbc, duckdb

Missing all the accent when select a parquet file Ind DuckDB ODBC

When I read a Parquet file from Power BI ODBC connection I’m missing all the accentuation

But if I open the same Parque file using Tad or even Dbevear it’s works fine

[SOLVED]

Open Control Panel.
Click Clock, Language, and Region, and then click Region and Language.
Click the Administrative tab, and then, under Language for non-Unicode programs, click Change system locale.
Select a new system locale and tap OK.

Comment: Hi! I was about to write that there is an issue record on GitHub for this topic when I saw the link in your question. I am also eager to have a working ODBC connection with PowerBI and DuckDB. I am not sure this is the right place for your question though. DBeaver (and I assume Tad as well) relies on JDBC driver not the ODBC. Moreover, the ODBC driver for v0.7.1 has more issues. According to the reply to your issue report, it should be solved with the v.0.8 As you are posting here, I reckoned it’s not solved? Did you try to use DuckDB‘s ODBC driver with any other client than PowerBI?

Comment: Can you use the built-in parquet connector? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/parquet Power BI is already a high-performance in-memory analysis engine.

Comment: @David, this should definitely work. If I am not mistaken, the high-performance in-memory analysis engine kicks in with DAX using the data model while the DuckDB ODBC works when creating the data model at the same stage as PowerQuery?

Comment: The ODBC only supports Import mode. So the data gets loaded into Power BI at refresh-time with either connector.

Comment: Sorry, I was not referring to Direct Query (which would run when using the data model in DAX, if I understand correctly). With “creating the data model at the same stage as PowerQuery” I consider it as the loading and creating  phase, where one could run a SQL query on the in-memory DuckDB engine during loading. Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong or not precise. Thanks!

Comment: I found this to better explain the “use case”: [https://datamonkeysite.com/2022/04/17/using-duckdb-with-powerbi/](https://datamonkeysite.com/2022/04/17/using-duckdb-with-powerbi/)

Comment: Ok, but as it apparently doesn't actually work correctly, why not just use Power Query to transform the incoming parquet file?  It's a common pattern to have Power Query send a SQL query to a RDBMS to do the initial processing, but when the RDBMS is in-process I don't see a compelling reason to do that.  You have to read the whole parquet file either way.

Comment: @Gustavo Leo: any news from your side? You closed your ticket there, so it’s fixed? There are more adjustments with the DuckDB ODBC driver to come with the next release as well: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/3627

Comment: Sorry, Anonymous. Yes, I closed the issue. I'm not sure how, but it's working now. It's likely that the advanced configuration for system location check on Windows was set to Unicode UTF-8.